# Assets UI fails (goes white) on local/dev, but works perfectly on prod

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, file-manager

I've got an odd issue where essentially the same Assets on production works fine, but fails on local/dev.

- Asset's native file manager does not display any images and just spins
- Inline-file manager within an entry does pop-up the Assets window, but is completely blank

The local/dev DB is imported from prod, and we're using Erik's Multi-config setup.

Is there a setting I need to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jae,

Sounds like a JS issue to me - check the browsers dev console and see what comes up there. The most common cause is cross-domain ajax issues.

Comment: Hey Andris, I'm getting the following error message: 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Same on both local and DEV environments. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jae,

judging by your comment on the question it might be the Session settings.

Assets makes a lot of Ajax requests and due to the nature of EE, they can only be made via frontend, so User session is used there to determine the access privileges, and when making those requests, Assets could not determine that the user was a valid CP user, so it denied every request as a security precaution.

Can you try changing Administration / Security and Session Preferences settings to Admin: Session And Cookies; User: Cookies.

That should resolve your issue.